# How to exchange EC2 Reserved No Upfront Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have three r4.xlarge Convertable reserved instances. 
Now I don't want these reserved instances. 
I want to exchange these reserved instances, I need two r5.xlarge and one r5a.xlarge. 
How can I exchange them?

Please advise.

Comment: Did you purchase **convertible** Reserved Instances? If so, contact customer service. If not, I don't think you can convert them unless you just bought them recently.

Comment: Yes, I purchased Convertible Reserved Instances with No Upfront.

Answer (score 0):

From [Exchanging Convertible Reserved Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-convertible-exchange.html):

> You can exchange one or more Convertible Reserved Instances for another Convertible Reserved Instance with a different configuration, including instance family, operating system, and tenancy. There are no limits to how many times you perform an exchange, as long as the target Convertible Reserved Instance is of an equal or higher value than the Convertible Reserved Instances that you are exchanging.
>
> When you exchange your Convertible Reserved Instance, the number of instances for your current reservation is exchanged for a number of instances that cover the equal or higher value of the configuration of the target Convertible Reserved Instance. Amazon EC2 calculates the number of Reserved Instances that you can receive as a result of the exchange.
>
> ...
>
> You can exchange your Convertible Reserved Instances using the Amazon EC2 console or a command line tool. Choose **Reserved Instances**, select the Convertible Reserved Instances to exchange, and choose Actions, **Exchange Reserved Instance**.

Basically, you will cash-in the remaining value on your existing Convertible Reserved Instances and use it as a credit for new Convertible Reserved Instances.